# Missing arch-specific emulator program error while launcing avd in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse ide for android developement. I have run my application in avd of andriod 2.1. It was working fine. I worked the whole day and then i turnoff my system. The next day I launched my eclipse but when I tried launch the avd I got `Missing arch-specific emulator program: E:\androidsdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe` error. How to overcome ths issue and start my AVD again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the SDK Manager and update everything. If that doesn't work, reinstall just the SDK manager, ADT plugin on eclipse should be fine.

Answer (score 18):

In my case, this was solved by doing the following:

- Launch Android SDK Tools > SDK Manager 
 - Under Tools folder, Choose Android SDK Tools
 - Choose 'Delete 1 Package' to remove Android SDK Tools
 - Get coffee.  Curse gods.
 - Choose 'Install 1 Package' to reinstall Android SDK Tools

Android emulator is a deep, deep hell, unto which much time must be sacrificed.  Hopefully this will add 10 minutes to someone's life.

~Ed

Comment: I loved this step: "Get coffee. Curse gods"

Answer (score 2):

I kept running into this on Mac OSX and it was driving me nuts.

I finally found out the issue was with the way I added the android tools dir to my PATH in my .bashrc

**Broken**:

`export PATH="~/android-sdks/tools:$PATH"`

**Fixed**:

`export PATH="$HOME/android-sdks/tools:$PATH"`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when trying to run the emulator through a symlink on the path. The emulator executable located at `/usr/bin/android-sdk/tools/emulator` could not find the other tool (`/usr/bin/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm`) since it was being run from my home folder instead of `/usr/bin/android-sdk/tools`.

I fixed it by putting the following script on my path where the symlink used to be:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh

#Get the folder of the script, so we can find the path
#that is relative to it
directory="$(dirname $0)"
$directory/android-sdk/tools/emulator "$@"
```

Comment: I found it worked by running `/non/linked/path/to/emulator` instead of `/linked/emulator`.